python2.7 асинхронно выполнить функции
Знаю что такая возможность есть в 3.5  и более новых. Но надо именно на 2.7!
Есть 2-3 функции. Все функции выполняют GET запрос и ждут пауза 1-5 минут sleep().
Как сделать пока одна функция спит запустить следующую функцию. Какой то простой event_loop для старого питона? а то получается первая функция ждет несколько часов пока данные появятся. Потом вторая функция и следующая. а потом уже сохраняется результат от обеих функций.
def one():
  while True:
    x = requests.get(url_1)
    # ждем повления данных, данных еще нет, спим
    sleep(5m)

def two():
  while True:
    x = requests.get(url_2)
    # ждем повления данных, данных еще нет, спим
    sleep(5m) 
    
def three():
  while True:
    x = requests.get(url_3)
    # ждем повления данных, данных еще нет, спим
    sleep(5m) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
  one()
  two()
  three()
  calc_and_save()  # вычисляем результат
  exit()

Хотелось бы пока пауза в 1й функции. Выполнить 2й и так далее.

gevent? twisted? Если функций всего три - могли бы и просто потоки запустить, зачем переусложнять себе жизнь асинхронщиной

while True: и sleep должен быть в main, а фукции должны только делать свою работу и возвращать true, если они получили новые данные.

@user7860670 теоретически там может быть блокирующий лонг-поллинг какой-нибудь

@andreymal Ну и пусть будет. Главное что бесполезных пауз по 5 минут между вызовами не будет.

Используйте Python 3.
